# Can you add higher authority to client on backend after SPA MSAL app login?

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-graph-api, dynamics-crm, azure-ad-msal

I would like to create an spa app with MSAL using react or nextjs. Is there a way to add a client secret or give higher authority on my backend after the user logged on from the spa version of MSAL?

What I am trying to do:
I want the user to log in and get their email from https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me in the spa.(Which I am currently getting).

Afterwards I want to send that email to my backend to call dynamics CRM. https://{TENANT}api/data/v9.0/accounts

Problem:
The spa wont have a client secret attached, so the access_token is public, not allowing me to make the CRM call. I tried to make it a web app instead, but the redirecting from that MSAL messes up on my frontend (The sessions cant be deleted properly). Can I do something with the MSAL SPA or do I need to find a work around on the webApp version?

Comment: Try to follow the tutorial here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-react and see if this is helpful.

Comment: Yeah, I followed that tutorial and 2 others lol. Just cant get everything I need to work yet. Honestly it would be best to have a service account but setting that up isnt working either. The fields are blocked and cant unblock them so trying this work around